# Using FFT to Unit Test a Music Player

Tags: ios, unit-testing, fft

I'd like to validate changes to our app music player in our Continuous Integration unit tests (more like integration tests, really). My thoughts were to start with an audio file that contains only a pure tone, or a series of pure tones. Our automated test would stream this file over the internet and play it through our player. We would capture the output using MTAudioProcessingTap. This output would go through and FFT and the pass/fail test would be check for the existence of only the original frequencies.

I'm thinking this would catch pops and glitches, but not necessarily discontinuities in the output.

Would this work?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this sort of thing on the signal processing stack exchange

Comment: What's your question?